# How to calculate difference of two fields on form submit Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, math, scaffolding

I am new to Ruby on Rails and have been using Scaffolding.  On one of the forms I want to be able to have two fields and then have the difference between the two submitted to the database.

Instead of :pickupamount, I want (Ending Amount - Starting Amount) to be calculated and entered into the pickupamount column of my database.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view:

```
form_tag '/some_action' do
    text_field_tag 'start_amount'
    text_field_tag 'end_amount'
end
```

In your controller:

```
def create
    model = Model.new
    model.pickupamount = params[:end_amount].to_i - params[:start_amount].to_i
    model.save!
end
```

Comment: The question mentioned Ending Amount - Starting Amount, and you show the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in either your model or your controller.  Going along with [Skinny Controller Fat Model](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model), it might be better to put the functionality in your model.  Check out [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :start_amount, :end_amount
  before_create :calculate_pickup_amount

  private
    def calculate_pickup_amount
      self.pickupamount = end_amount.to_i - start_amount.to_i
    end
end
```

Then, in your controller:

```
def create
  # Assuming params[:my_model] has all the data for initializing a MyModel,
  # including start_amount and end_amount but not pickupamount:
  my_model = MyModel.new(params[:my_model])

  if my_model.save
    # Yay, do something
  else
    # Fail, do something else
  end
end
```

It might be useful to include the following extension method to Ruby's `String` class (thanks to [sikelianos](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5003)), perhaps in a file in your Rails app's lib directory:

```
class String
  def numeric?
    Float self rescue false
  end
end
```

Then you could perform a check before setting `pickupamount`:

```
def calculate_pickup_amount
  if end_amount.numeric? && start_amount.numeric?
    self.pickupamount = end_amount.to_i - start_amount.to_i
  else
    # Throw exception, set some default value, etc.
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Sarah, just stumbled across this looking for an answer to a simliar problem. ActiveRecord Callbacks are exactly what I needed to solve my problem.